# Python polars find next values that meet predicament

Tags: python, loops, vectorization

Given this polars dataframe (simplified the datetime to be ints),

```
testDF = DataFrame({
"datetime": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
"values":   [3, 2, 5, 4, 8, 4]}
```

What is the fastest approach to obtain another column, with the next future value of each value, that meets the criteria: abs(future_value - original_value) >= 2, and adding also the date of that future value that has been found as another column:

Resulting in this:

```
"datetime":                [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5   ],
"values":                  [3, 2, 5, 4, 8, 4   ],
"future_value":            [5, 5, 8, 8, 4, None],
"future_value_datetime":   [2, 2, 4, 4, 5, None]
```

I know how to do it with iterrows, but this is part of a more complex calculation, and I would like to know the exact method on how to do it in the most efficient and best way possible in polars.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework.  What have you tried? What problems have you run into.  We'll help you with your code, but you've got to try and write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps:

```
abs_more_2 = abs(testDF['values'].values.reshape(-1,1) - testDF['values'].values.reshape(1,-1)) >= 2
abs_more_2 = np.where(abs_more_2)
res = abs_more_2[1] > abs_more_2[0] # select only those which are after current item
res[res] = abs_more_2[0][res] != np.roll(abs_more_2[0][res], 1) # select only the first value which is under condition
index = testDF['values'].index.map(dict(zip(abs_more_2[0][res], abs_more_2[1][res]))) # for each current index select future index
# insert values according to a future index
testDF['future_value'] = testDF['values'][index].values
testDF['future_value_datetime'] = testDF['datetime'][index].values
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!. While that works, I am wondering if there is no other oneliner all in polars solution. Hummm, this seems complicated and maybe not as efficient as one all polars solution maybe?